# UPDATE of hashed field from a source View to target Table runs indefinitely

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, hashbytes

I have source View which is being used to populate a target Table. I recently added 2 new columns to the View and thus included them into the existing HASHBYTES function. Here is what the new *content_hash* looks like in the View:

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), HASHBYTES('SHA2_512',
                CONCAT(ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), FORMAT(tl.[TRANSACTION_ID],'#')), 'NULL TRANSACTIONUID'), '|'
                ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), FORMAT(tl.[COMPANY_ID],'#')), 'NULL PROJECTUID'), '|'
                ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), FORMAT(tl.[DEPARTMENT_ID],'#')), 'NULL OPERATINGGROUPUID'), '|'
                ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), FORMAT(d.[DEPARTMENT_ID],'#')), 'NULL SO_OPERATINGGROUPUID'), '|' --added per User Story #4626
                ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),cx.modifiedon), 'NULL IV_MODIFIEDON'), '|' --added per User Story #4652
                ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), FORMAT(tl.[OPENAIR_IS_PERSON_ID],'#')), 'NULL RESOURCEUID'), '|'
                ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), FORMAT(tl.[SUBSIDIARY_ID],'#')), 'NULL LEGALENTITYUID'), '|'
                ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), FORMAT(tl.[ACCOUNT_ID],'#')), 'NULL GLACCOUNTUID'), '|'
                ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), FORMAT(tl.[CLASS_ID],'#')), 'NULL GLCLASSUID'), '|'
                ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), FORMAT(c.[PARENT_ID],'#')), 'NULL CLIENTUID'), '|'
                ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), a.[TYPE_NAME]), 'NULL GLACCOUNTTYPEUID'), '|'
                ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), FORMAT(t.[TRANDATE],'YYYYMMDD')), 'NULL TRANDATE'), '|'
                ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), FORMAT(tl.[AMOUNT],'#.############')), 'NULL AMOUNT'), '|'
                ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), FORMAT(tl.[AMOUNT_LINKED],'#.############')), 'NULL AMOUNT'), '|'
                ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), FORMAT(tl.[AMOUNT_PENDING],'#.############')), 'NULL AMOUNT'), '|'
                ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), [NON_POSTING_LINE]), 'NULL NONPOSTINGLINE'), '|'
                ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), tl.[OPENAIR_ITEM_DESCRIPTION]), 'NULL Desc'), '|'
                ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), FORMAT(tl.[DATE_CREATED],'yyyyMMdd HH:MM:ss')), 'NULL TRANDATE'), '|'
                ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), FORMAT(tl.[DATE_LAST_MODIFIED_GMT],'yyyyMMdd HH:MM:ss')), 'NULL LAST_MODIFIED')
                ))) 
                as content_hash
```

The issue I'm having though is running an UPDATE that will set the target Table *content_hash* to the result of the *content_hash* from the View. The UPDATE just runs indefinitely and never finishes (I've let it go for up to 2hrs).

```
UPDATE tgt
    SET
        tgt.content_hash = src.content_hash
    FROM dbo.[gl_transaction_line] tgt
    INNER JOIN dbo.src_gl_transaction_line src 
        ON tgt.gl_transaction_line_uid = src.gl_transaction_line_uid
```

The resultset of the View is about 6.46M records. Running the full View in isolation takes about 11-12 mins which is how long it was taking before the 2 new fields were added.

Is there anything I can do to improve performance or an alternative way I can set the *content_hash* in the target Table to match the View?

This is just a one-time need where I need to update the *content_hash* across the entire table. It's because we don't want the stored procedure which normally loads the target table at night to see all of these *content_hash* differences and capture it in the history table. The target Table is normally temporal but I'm temporarily reverting it to non-temporal to make these (stealth) updates and then re-enabling it otherwise our history would double in size since every record is being touched by the addition of these two new fields.

**EDIT**
I have limited permissions in the environment that I'm working in but will share what I can and post more if I can get it.

In general, we have stored procedures in our warehouse that execute as part of our nightly refresh. These Sp's compare the source Views to their target temporal Tables to determine whether an Insert, Update, Delete or *nothing* should happen. I'll share the beginning snippet of the related sp but this is why we're using the *content_hash*. If there's a better approach to all of this I'm all ears. I'm still relatively new to this environment so I can't speak to why things are architected the way they were but I'm glad to iterate towards a better solution.

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#processing_path') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #processing_path END

SELECT          ISNULL(src.gl_transaction_line_uid, tgt.gl_transaction_line_uid) as gl_transaction_line_uid
                , CASE WHEN tgt.gl_transaction_line_uid IS NULL 
                        THEN 'Insert'
                    WHEN src.gl_transaction_line_uid IS NULL 
                        THEN 'Delete'
                    WHEN src.content_hash != tgt.content_hash
                        THEN 'Update'
                    ELSE 'Unchanged' END AS processing_path
                , tgt.version_begin_timestamp
INTO            #processing_path
FROM            dbo.src_gl_transaction_line src
 FULL JOIN      dbo.[gl_transaction_line] tgt ON src.gl_transaction_line_uid = tgt.gl_transaction_line_uid

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_uc ON #processing_path (gl_transaction_line_uid)
```

So depending on which *processing_path* that a record from the source View is assigned then that dictates whether those records are handled by the DELETE, UPDATE or INSERT queries further down in the sp.

**EDIT 2**
I was able to get a co-worker to capture the actual execution plan of the source View. I see there is an expensive clustered index scan (64% cost) and it's recommending a non-clustered index be created. I will try this tomorrow and see how that helps things.

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyvbS1miT

**Side Note:** I did also remove all of the nested FORMAT functions inside the HASHBYTES function and even removed a couple of the CONVERT VARCHAR functions as they were unnecessary. Just doing this alone did improve the runtime performance of the View by a couple of minutes but the UPDATE attempt still ran indefinitely.

Comment: I count 15 format()'s   ... Do you not like your data?

Comment: Perhaps part of the problem is the `VIEW`as well as the query above.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti haha, this is not my original source code. I'm stepping in and simply trying to help support the current situation. That said, do you think that could actually be a factor in the performance of the UPDATE?

Comment: Format() has some great functionality, but the performance is poor.  It should be used sparingly.

Comment: 11-12 minutes for 6m rows sounds very slow. Please share the execution plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan and please also show the full tables, indexes and view definitions.

Comment: @ThomA Let me guess: someone decided that it's faster to hash all the columns (using a very slow hash function to boot because "security") and then compare the hashes (and never mind collisions) rather than just doing `SELECT a.whatever EXCEPT SELECT b.whatever`. Let's not even get into using `FORMAT` and *then* converting to `varchar`, and then converting the 512bit (128hex) hash into `nvarchar` of all types, and cutting it off at 100 characters. I mean who thinks these things up.

Comment: I suspect that if we can see the real queries, we will find several cans full of worms, @Charlieface

Comment: @Charlieface I'll try to get this info, in particular the execution plan as I agree that would be helpful but I have limited permission in the environment. I'm going to amend my original post with some general info for now until I can share more. If you have a generally better approach to share please let me know. TIA

Comment: @Charlieface I don't disagree with the sentiment. But technically `HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', ...)` will output 64 bytes, and then because of UCS-2 encoding wrapping `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(...), ...)` around that will pack the 64 bytes into `NVARCHAR(32)`. It's still nonsense.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I kind of assumed (as did probably the coder) that it would format it as hex so 128 chars, but it doesn't under style 0, it just assumes they are already UCS-2 like you say.

Comment: @Charlieface I was able to get the actual execution plan of the View. Please see the EDITS to my original post. TIA

Comment: That's not the plan for the query above. And quite clearly, you are using a view, not a bare table, for which we don't have the definition, nor do we have the definitions for the tables in the view. All we can say at this point is that the indexing is terrible to non-existent, and there is some fiendishly complex self-joining on the `company_primaryKeys` table. The hashing and the use of `FORMAT` are probably the least of your worries judging by that plan. I'm afraid this is not answerable without much more info.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - SQL Server doesn't care if it contains a `U+0000` - it doesn't truncate this. Just client tools will when displaying it. https://dbfiddle.uk/7VPmC8gb `NVARCHAR` is still clearly the wrong choice for binary data though as don't want string comparison semantics. Even if binary collate clause is used trailing spaces will still be ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the update (which uses the view) takes ages to run, I would suggest splitting it up into two separate processes for this 'one-off' run.

Part 1: Get the data into a temporary table
e.g.,

```
CREATE TABLE #TempHashes (gl_transaction_line_uid int PRIMARY KEY, content_hash nvarchar(100));

INSERT INTO #TempHashes (gl_transaction_line_uid, content_hash)
SELECT gl_transaction_line_uid, content_hash
FROM dbo.src_gl_transaction_line;
```

Part 2: Then simply do an update of the original table, with the new hashes, joining on the ID, using the pre-calculated hashes.

I find that this sort of strategy tends to work - I cannot truly explain why (there are people here who probably could) but I suspect that it has to do with how it is running the hashing view, and in particular, how many times it runs. The simpler 'just put the results into a temporary table' means it runs the hashing calculations as efficiently as possible; then the update using the temporary table is also very easy/efficient for the planner to create a good execution plan.

NOTE: As per comments, there are many issues with this view. The above is as a way to get the job done in the current situation with minimal other changes - assuming the situation is that it typically "works" (no matter how inefficiently) but you need to do this one-off whole-table data update.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll give this a try if all else fails, but I agree that the root of the issue is with the View. I've updated my original post with the actual execution plan and there is room for improvement.

Comment: Remember that those %s are estimates, not actuals - and can be drastically wrong. For example, in this case, the clustered scan (estimate: 64%) took 17 and a quarter seconds; the calculation of the convert/format/isnulls (estimate: 0%) took 8 minutes and 16 seconds. And that plan is for the SELECT (which takes 11-12 mins, as you said) but the problem is when you do the UPDATE (which may run the same query multiple times).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the execution plan. I ended up taking the approach in your first response and that got us over the hump. I have an internal ticket open for us to come back and performance tune the source View as there are obviously issues that need addressed.

Comment: I think that is the right approach. My mentor taught me that in a business setting, "if it works and there's no need to change it, then don't change it, no matter how bad it is". Though it pains me greatly to say it (and the temptation to ignore it can be great), fixing, testing, and implementing a change could easily be more than 4 hours work for no practical business benefit. And if there are other views that do the same sort of thing (e.g., with other tables), then this one may not be the worst - and the person then fixing them all would then have to deal with inconsistent approaches.